# Rendering 1000+ div in web page

Tags: html, dom

I am completly novice to html and related stuff. Although I just wanted to check if there is any way we can display 1000+ div in a web page withough making it slow. 
When I tried to do that my web page becomes extremely slow and does now allow me to scroll the page in which these divs are added.
Any link/ page will greatly be appiciated.
PS . I am using IE8. This works perfectly in mozilla and chrome though
Thanks in advance
Samir

Comment: WHy would you want to do that?

Comment: Than you are designing the wrong way

Comment: I believe FB has a lot of divs...

Comment: @hallie I am damn sure no one will attempt to make another fb now

Comment: If you do have huge number of content divs to display, I would suggest you consider using AJAX to load them dynamically. That would reduce the load of first time the page is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on the content of the divs and the css and other items on the page.

This test created a page that had no problem loading in any browser:

```
function test() {
       for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
        echo "<div>" . $i . "</div>";
       }
    }
```